# Need help in file filtering

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a list of host names in file A and also one more file with complete host names details in file B.I want to remove the hosts which all matches A hosts in B file.Any short script to do this?Please let me know.

Ex:

```
cat A 
server1
server2
server3
server4 

cat B
server700
server1
server300
server4
```

So here in A and B ,server1 and server4 are matching,So I need a script where it removes all matching servers names fromB in A file

Comment: Please, be more specific. Show a sample of both the files and expected output. What do you mean by "which all matches A hosts in B file"?

Comment: Ex: cat A
server1
server2
server3
server4

cat B
server700
server1
server300
server4

So here in A and B ,server1 and server4 are matching,So I need a script where it removes all matching servers in both the files

Comment: Edit your question to include this info. Use the `{}` tool at top left of edit box after selecting text with mouse to give it proper formatting. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Something on these lines might help you out. Adjust regular expression on the grep command to be sure to only match hostnames on the details file:

```
cat file_with_hostnames | while read hname; do grep -q "$hname" file_with_host_details || echo $hname; done
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response...Please check the below example and let me know if you have suggestion for below ...
Ex: cat A
server1
server2
server3
server4

cat B
server700
server1
server300
server4

So here in A and B ,server1 and server4 are matching,So I need a script where it removes all matching servers names  from the files

Answer (score 1):

Something could be like,

```
diff A B | grep "[>|<]" > temp_op
cat temp_op | grep ">" | cut -f2 -d " " > new_B 
cat temp_op | grep "<" | cut -f2 -d " " > new_A
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what do you mean by [>|<] this symbol

Comment: diff provides output in form of > (data not matching from file1) and < (data not matching from file2) and we want data in a file so we are selecting that with grep.  [>|<] this filter mean lines which has < or > in it. try diff command in linux

Answer (score 0):

```
comm --output-delimiter="|" -3 A B|sed 's/^|//'
```

Note 1: This requires GNU `comm`.
Note 2: `comm(1)` requires the files be sorted.
Note 3: The weirdness with the '|' character is because `comm` will not allow an empty `output-delimiter`.  Go figure.